# Can mysqli tell you field data type and length set

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is there a way for php mysqli to return the field type and length.  I know that `mysqli_result::fetch_fields` can return the field type like `INT` but not the length that is set to.

`INT(11)`

I want get the "11" not the longest field record that is currently in table.

When I run a `DESCRIBE table_name` I get the information I want.

`Field_type(LENGTH)`

`INT(11)`

Comment: Another way would be to execute `describe yourTableName`, and get the desired info from the result... just an idea

Comment: So did you answer your own question here?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know PHP, but I think that what I proposed in my comment would help you:

Use `describe yourTable` to get the field list, the result will give you also the data type of each field.

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont just try to query `DESCRIBE`, try it.

```
$link = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$query = mysqli_query($link, 'DESCRIBE `your_table_name`');
$desired_column = 'id';
$id = null;
while($result = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($result['Field'] == $desired_column) {
        $field_type = $result['Type'];
        preg_match('#\((.*?)\)#', $field_type, $match);
        $id = $match[1];
    }
}

echo $id; // 11
```

Comment: I just want length "11" not the whole "int(11)"